# ItemUpdated event not firing when list item updated from another event receiver

Tags: event-receivers, itemupdated, item-updating

I have two lists **List1** and **List2**. I have written code to update List2 item from **ItemUpdating** event of List1. This should fire **ItemUpdated** event of List2 but it does not. Below is the code I used to update List2 item.

```
var list = web.Lists["List2"];    
var item = list.GetItemById(Id);

item["City"] = "CityA";
item.Update();
```

List2 events fires when there is manual update in list but only failing in above case. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're not doing a `web.EventFiringEnabled = false` anywhere are you?

Comment: Yes i've written this statement but it is for List1. Is it affecting List2 from firing its events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've stated that you're doing a `web.EventFiringEnabled = false` in the event receiver for List1.

This will disable event firing across your entire web, including for List2. This explains why your event receiver for List2 is not firing.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that base.EventFiringEnabled will affect entire site collection. I think I will have to improve my code in order to prevent list item from firing ItemUpdated event.